# HTTPBuilder get method with closure parameter return MissingMethodException

Tags: groovy, httpbuilder, missingmethodexception

below code:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://twitter.com/statuses/' )

http.get( path: 'user_timeline.json', 
    query: [id:'httpbuilder', count:5] ) { resp, json ->

    println resp.status

    json.each {  // iterate over JSON 'status' object in the response:
        println it.created_at
        println '  ' + it.text
    }
}
```

Why get exception? I use the same code from http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/json.html, it should works.

Comment: Works fine for me; what versions of everything are you using? Also, the stack trace/some context is helpful.

Comment: I think it's may be my IDE's problem, I use Spring Tool Suite 2.6. The exception information is that it can not find method  public Object get(Map<String, ?> args, Closure responseClosure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's IDE's problem, Eclipse groovy plugin not works very well.